# Question on Integration.

Tags: integration

We know that $\displaystyle\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\ln|f(x)|+C$.

I try to compute $\displaystyle\int\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2dx$ and $\displaystyle\int x\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2dx$. Can we compute them?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you looked for an example?

Comment: I would like to find the close form of them. Can we do?

Comment: I don’t think we can, for general $f$.